# Determine sparsity of sparse matrix ( Lil matrix )

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix, implemented as a lil sparse matrix from sci-py. I just want a statistic for how sparse the matrix is once populated. Is there a method to find out this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m.nnz` is the number of nonzero elements in the matrix `m`, you can use `m.size` to get the total number of elements.